# Rscript does not work when invoked in PHP but does from Command Prompt

Tags: php, r, rscript

I am trying to execute an R script from my PHP page using the exec function. I have set the environment variables in Windows and Rscript works fine on the command prompt. However on the PHP page it says, " 'Rscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you pass the full path to Rscript to PHP?

Comment: I passed the full path of my R script named my_rscript.R. How do I pass the full path of Rscript?

Comment: I mean the full path of the `Rscript.exe` binary, not your script file.

Comment: No. How do I do that? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define a `launcher.bat` where I deal will all `R-paths` problem:

```
PATH PATH_TO_R/R-version/bin;%path%
cd PATH_TO_R_SCRIPT
Rscript myscript.R arg1 arg2
```

Then in the `php` side you can use `exec`:

```
   <?php
exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START PATH_TO_LAUNCHER\LAUNCHER.bat');
?>
```

Comment: I really want to integrate it into my webpage. Is running a batch file really advisable? Coz every time I pass on a value I see a command window open up and all the commands executing. Is there a way to this without that happening?

Comment: I've been spending soooo much time on this issue and this was the first solution that got the Rscript to run from the php code in the browser.  I would be grateful, as @user1523478 mentioned, to have this work without the cmd popup window.  Any suggestions are welcome.  Thanks!