# batch execute R script

Tags: r, batch-processing, rstudio

I am unable to source a script from the windows command line.

Entering the following command:
"C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\rstudio.exe" CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave "E:\myfile.R"

Opens Rstudio and the script in question, but does not source.  Documentation notes you may specify an output file but I just want the script to execute.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You should use `Rscript`  not rstudio! See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817206/rscript-does-not-work-when-invoked-in-php-but-does-from-command-prompt/17817707#17817707) for example.

Comment: Thanks agstudy, that got me there.  R is a huge learning curve...love it though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agstudy's answer is all you need but as reference to others I only used two lines:

PATH C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin;%path%
Rscript "E:\Dir With Spaces\myfile.R"

Note the path points to R and not Rstudio.  The quotes in line 2 deal with Dir With Spaces.