# Execute R script in R studio using batch file

Tags: r, batch-file

I want to execute a R script in R Studio using batch file. I know how to execute R script using batch file in R though. When I try to execute using the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\rstudio.exe" CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave "C:\Users\kpappala\Desktop\R schedule\task.R"
```

It just opens R studio but doesn't execute. Is there a way?

 Thanks!

Comment: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/06/running-scripts-with-r-cmd-batch.html or https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/BATCH.html or http://www.cureffi.org/2014/01/15/running-r-batch-mode-linux/ or http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html

Answer (score 2):

Rstudio is an IDE for R.  It isn't R though.  It doesn't really even make sense to run it in batch through rstudio.

If you're just saying you want to run a file from within Rstudio that's different and you can just source it or run it in batch via system using a call to R CMD BATCH.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered here:
[batch execute R script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872592/batch-execute-r-script).

In short and as Dason said, you Rstudio is just a shell, and doesn't actually run the code. For that use R. Try this instead:

PATH C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin;%path%
Rscript "C:\Users\kpappala\Desktop\R schedule\task.R"